# swap multiple objects in char array with one another at the same time

Tags: c++, arrays, char, c-strings

I'm trying to make a program using a c-string (no std:string allowed for this one) in which the contents of the c-string are a name formatted : lastName, firstName middleName or as the program will treat it lastName, firstMiddleName.

What I want to do is simply switch the format to firstMiddleName lastName.

I'm wondering if there's some elegant way to do so by possibly using an index to find the comma in order separate the two parts of the c-string, and then just something similar to str.substr(0, index) in order to swap the two around easily. Is this possible at all? I feel like I've exhausted every thread on the matter

any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Not really. Make another string and save the new string to that, then copy it back.

Comment: Switching the names around inline with swaps will not be an elegant solution.  It will be more elegant to find the names and then build a new string out of them.  Note that the `substr` function you mentioned actually builds a new string.

Comment: So what have you tried, elegant  or not?  If you provide some evidence of effort, I may provide just the tiniest bit of recursion to help you.  Oops, I just gave you a hint.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is better to create `struct` for person with last name and first name.

```
typedef struct {
    char* firstname;
    char* lastname;
} person_t;
```

To split string by some separator you can use `strtok` function like this

```
char* last = strtok(str, ",");
```

where `str` is the source string and `,` is separator.

Now you need to create an instance of the `person_t` and copy values

```
person_t create_person(char* firstname, char* lastname) {
    person_t person;
    int length;

    length = strlen(firstname);
    person.firstname = malloc(sizeof(char) * (length + 1));
    person.firstname[length] = '\0';

    length = strlen(lastname);
    person.lastname = malloc(sizeof(char) * (length + 1));
    person.lastname[length] = '\0';

    strcpy(person.firstname, firstname);
    strcpy(person.lastname, lastname);

    return person;
}
```

Now you can output these values as you want. See full code below

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct {
    char* firstname;
    char* lastname;
} person_t;

person_t create_person(char* firstname, char* lastname) {
    person_t person;
    int length;

    length = strlen(firstname);
    person.firstname = malloc(sizeof(char) * (length + 1));
    person.firstname[length] = '\0';

    length = strlen(lastname);
    person.lastname = malloc(sizeof(char) * (length + 1));
    person.lastname[length] = '\0';

    strcpy(person.firstname, firstname);
    strcpy(person.lastname, lastname);

    return person;
}

int main(void) {
    char str[] = "Surname, Firstname Middlename";
    char* last = strtok(str, ",");
    char* first = strtok(NULL, ",") + 1;
    person_t person = create_person(first, last);
    printf("firstname: %s\nlastname: %s\n", person.firstname, person.lastname);
    return 0;
}
```

The output of the above code is

> firstname: Firstname Middlename
>
> lastname: Surname

Also don't forget to clean up ;)

```
void remove_person(person_t person) {
    free(person.firstname);
    free(person.lastname);
}
```

Comment: `malloc(1 + sizeof(char) * strlen(firstname))` ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You have tagged this question for C++.

Here I present two versions.

t266a() conforms to c++ and streams, but uses only c-string (no std::string)

t266b() conforms to c++ and streams, and uses std::string (no c-string)

I intentionally used blank space to align sections of the code-with-c-strings to the code-with-std::strings, but you will need to load this into a capable editor to show them side by side.

```
//  1 & 2 of 3 c++ includes
#include <iostream>    // cout, cin, istream
#include <algorithm>   // std::fill

// removed: include <cstring> - not needed

// forward

// c++, but limited to c-string, no std::string
int t266a(std::istream& ss);

// c++, using std::string
int t266b(std::istream& ss);

const int MAX_BUFF = (1024*1024); // for c-string, how big should this be?
// default stack size ubuntu 15.10 (64) is 8MB, so plenty of room


// ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
size_t getLine (std::istream& ss, char* buff, size_t& buffLen)
{
   size_t karCount  = 0;
   for (size_t i=0; i<MAX_BUFF; ++i) // limit read to MAX_BUFF chars
   {
      char kar  = 0;

      ss.read(&kar, 1);  // binary stream read, 1 char at a time

      if (ss.eof()) break;

      if(ss.bad()) { // either fail or bad
         std::cerr << "stream bad x " << std::endl;
         break;
      }

      buff[i]   = kar;  // capture kar to buff
      karCount += 1;    // count kar's

      if ('\n' == buff[i])  // end-of-line within stream
      {
         buffLen = i;
         buff[i] = 0; // null-terminate in buff
         break;  // line complete
      }
   }
   return(karCount);
}

// ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
size_t buffFind(const char* buff, size_t buffLen, const char kar)
{
   size_t commaAt  =  buffLen + 1; // not found

   for (size_t i=0; i<buffLen; ++i)
   {
      if(kar == buff[i])
      {
         commaAt = i;   // found comma
         break;
      }
   }

   return (commaAt);
}

// ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// c++, but limited to c-string, no std::string
int t266a(std::istream& ss)
{
   std::cout << "t266a() C++, but limited to c-string, no std::string" << std::endl;

   std::cout << "MAX_BUFF: " << MAX_BUFF << std::endl;

   char buff[MAX_BUFF];

   size_t buffCount = 0;
   size_t buffLen   = 0;

   do
   {
      // buff[0] = '\0';                      // a c-string terminates with the 1st 0 ... need to clear all?
      // (void)::memset(buff, 0, MAX_BUFF);   // from   <cstring> lib.  clear all  c-style
      std::fill(buff, buff+MAX_BUFF, '\0');   // from <algorithm> lib.  clear all  c++style

      (void)getLine(ss, buff, buffLen);  // local function

      if(ss.eof()) break;

      if(ss.bad()) { // either fail or bad
         std::cerr << " " << ss.good()
                   << " " << ss.eof()
                   << " " << ss.fail()
                   << " " << ss.bad()
                   << std::endl;
         break;
      }

      buffCount += 1;

      if (ss.eof()) break;

      //std::cout << "  Input: " << buffCount << "  (" << buffLen << ")  '" << buff << "'" << std::endl;

      // find comma
      size_t commaAt  =  buffFind(buff, buffLen, ',');

      if(commaAt > buffLen)
      {
         std::cerr << " Err: invalid input: no comma on line "<< std::endl;
         break;
      }

      if(commaAt < 1)
      {
         std::cerr << " Err: invalid input: comma at beginning of line "<< std::endl;
         break;
      }

      buff[commaAt] = 0;              // take advantage of c-string
      std::cout << " Output:          "
                << &buff[commaAt+1]  // Firstname Middlename [(where comma was) .. (end of buff)]
                << "  "
                << &buff[0]          // Surname [0..(where comma was)]
                << "  (bufLen: " << buffLen << ")"  << std::endl;

      if (ss.eof()) { break;}

   }while (true);

   return(0);

} // int t266a(std::istream&)


// ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// 3 of 3 c++ includes
#include <sstream>

// ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
int main(int argc, char* argv[] )
{
   std::cout << "argc: " << argc << std::endl;
   for (int i=0; i<argc; i+=1) std::cout << argv[i] << " ";
   std::cout << std::endl;

   setlocale(LC_ALL, "");

   std::stringstream ssTest;
   {
      for (int i=1; i<=8; ++i) // 8 entries
      {
         ssTest  << "Surname" << i << ", Firstname" << i << " Middlename" << i << "\n";
      }
      // add test cases here
      // trailing spaces --------------------------------vv
      // ssTest <<  " SurnameX,   FirstnameX  MiddlenameX  \n" ;
      //             ^--leading spaces
      // ssTest <<  "SnameY, FnameY MnameY\n" ;
      // different size names
   }

   int retVal = 0;
   {
      std::stringstream ss (ssTest.str()); // load ss

      std::cout << "\nistream (input): \n" << ss.str() << std::endl;

      retVal += t266a(ss); // run c++ using c-strings
   }

   {
      std::stringstream ss(ssTest.str()); // load ss

      std::cout << "\n\nistream (input): \n" << ss.str() << std::endl;

      retVal += t266b(ss); // run c++ using std::string
   }

   std::cout << "\n\nFINI " << std::endl;
   return(retVal);
}


// ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// c++, but using std::string (no c-strings)
int t266b(std::istream& ss)
{
   std::cout << "t266b() C++, using std::string (no c-strings)" << std::endl;



   std::string buff; // buff grows as needed

   size_t buffCount = 0;     // line count
   //size_t buffLen = 0;     // now buff.size()

   do
   {


      buff.clear();

      (void)std::getline(ss, buff); // uses default delim ('\n')

      if(ss.eof()) break;

      if(ss.bad()) { // bad or fail bit set
         std::cerr << " " << ss.good()
                   << " " << ss.eof()
                   << " " << ss.fail()
                   << " " << ss.bad()
                   << std::endl;
         break;
      }

      buffCount += 1;

      if (ss.eof()) break;

      //std::cout << "  Input: " << buffCount << "  (" << buff.size() << ")  '" << buff << "'" << std::endl;

      // find comma
      size_t commaAt = buff.find(',');

      if(commaAt == std::string::npos)
      {
         std::cerr << " Err: invalid input: no comma  " << std::endl;
         break;
      }

      if(commaAt < 1)
      {
         std::cerr << " Err: invalid input: comma at beginning of line "<< std::endl;
         break;
      }


      std::cout << " Output:          "
                << buff.substr(commaAt+1)  // Firstname Middlename [(where comma was) .. (end of buff)]
                << "  "
                << buff.substr(0, commaAt) // Surname [0..(where comma was)]
                << "  (buff.size(): " << buff.size() << ")"  << std::endl;

      if (ss.eof()) { break;}

   }while (true);

   return(0);

} // int t266b(std::istream&)
```